# HP Fortify issues Weak XML unbounded occurrence

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, xml-parsing

I have used *maxOccurs="unbounded"* in my XML schema and I can rectify it by providing an upper limit on the occurrences of objects i.e. 2147483647.

My concern is, will it allocate the memory at compile time as **2147483647*(object size)** or it will be just an upper limit and memory will be allocated while parsing the request at runtime?